# Static field initialization order (C#) - can someone explain this snippet?

Tags: c#, static-members

I am a C++ programmer learning C#. I am currently reading C#4.0 in a Nutshell.

I have come accross this statement/snipet on page 74:

> Static field initializers run in the
>   order in which the fields are
>   declared. The following example
>   illustrates this: X is initialized to
>   0 and Y is initialized to 3.

```
class Foo
{
    public static int X = Y; // 0
    public static int Y = 3; // 3
}
```

I dont understand how X can be assigned the value in Y, without Y being first declared. Am I missing something here?

As an aside, coming from a C++ background, I tend to use the term ctor for constructor - however, I haven't yet come accross the term in C# - is the term ctor also used in the C# world?

**[Edit]**

A further example on the same page (in the book mentioned earlier) is this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main() { Console.WriteLine (Foo.X); } // 3
}
class Foo
{
    public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
    public static int X = 3;
    Foo() { Console.WriteLine (X); } // 0
}
```

The book states (for the example above):

> The example prints 0 followed by 3
>   because the field initializer that
>   instantiates a Foo executes before X
>   is initialized to 3:

I have some further questions w.r.t the examples.

1. Both examples appear under the section entitled **Static constructors and field initialization order** however, the code examples dont show a static ctor - atleast, not one that I can easily recognise. I was expecting a static ctor to have the same name as the class, be parameterless and be preceeded by the '*static*' keyword. So I dont see how the examples relate to the section heading. What am I missing here?
2. In the second example, the (non static) ctor prints out the value of X - which had **explicitly** been assigned the value of 3 in the previous line - and yet, the output printed out is 0. Why?!

Comment: Internally, .NET uses `ctor` to mean "constructor" and `cctor` to mean "class constructor" (the function that initializes those static variables X and Y in your example). While not commonly used when discussing C#, the terms do show up in the language spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, primitive types such as `int` take on a default value.  For `int`, the default value is 0.  This is not like C++ where you have to initialize the value or it will be getting a random dirty value from memory.  Since Y is known to be of type `int`, X can be assigned it's default value of 0.

As far as the keyword `ctor`, I don't see it used very much as a C# programmer, but I am familiar with the term.  I believe it is used in a few places in Visual Studio, for instance in the object browser.

Comment: `ctor` is also the term used in IL (and `cctor` is used for static constructors)

Comment: @Porges: Good to know.  I've never actually dug into any IL :)

Comment: You wrote: "Since Y is known to be of type int" ... How do we know that Y is an int?. At the point where X is assigned to Y, Y has not yet been defined (at least, as far as I can see from reading the code).

Comment: @voidstar: The compiler doesn't require everything to be declared before it's used - it performs several phases of compilation. You can assume that when it's making decisions like this, it has visibility of the whole code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ah, so we are dealing with a multi pass compiler - things starting to make some sense now.

Answer (score 7):

Order of declaration isn't important in terms of what's *available* here. It's not like the case where these are *local* variables, and a variable is only available after it's declared. The same is true for instance variables - and indeed methods, where a method declared earlier in the source can call one declared later in the source, etc.

However, the order of declaration *is* important in terms of execution of initializers, which is why you're getting that behaviour. Note that if you change these variables to `const`, both will take the value 3 - the compiler will work out the required order of evaluation, and will detect if there are any cycles (Which would cause an error). The constants would then be evaluated at *compile*-time, and the values embedded directly in IL.

For more details about what's valid etc, consult [the specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc).

As for terminology - I don't usually see the need to abbreviate "constructor" to "ctor", although I think it would be generally understood. I might use that abbreviation for a variable name, for example:

```
var ctor = typeof(...).GetConstructor(...);
```

Comment: If you change these variables to const, they are just constant values, there is no initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

Field declaration doesn't need to be in the order of dependency.

That is, you can use `Y` above where you declare `Y`.

The initialization, however, goes like this:

- `X` is initialized first, grabs its value from `Y`, which is uninitialized, and thus `0` (the default value for an `int`)
- `Y` is initialized to `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialisers are actually run in the constructor of the class. When the class is created, all static members are set to zero, then the static constructor runs. That is why the initialiser code can use the `Y` field to initialise the `X` field.

Your code works basically the same as:

```
class Foo {

  public static int X; // 0
  public static int Y; // 0

  static Foo() {
    X = Y; // 0
    Y = 3; // 3
  }

}
```

(There are however some differences between a class that has an explicit static constructor and one that doesn't, see [Jon Skeet's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) if you want to dig deeper.)

The term "ctor" is not widely used for "constructor" in C#, usually abbreviations like that are avoided in .NET. That is why identifiers tend to be lengthy and descriptive rather than short and cryptic, like `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` rather than something like `str_cmp.cc_is`.

The abbreviation "ctor" is used in the templates in Visual Studio, by typing "ctor" and pressing tab, you get a template for a constructor.

Comment: This code isn't showing any instances, or an instance constructor. Also note that a class without a static constructor has different behaviour to one with a static constructor, due to the beforefieldinit flag.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, you are right, there is no instance. I corrected the answer.

Comment: You may want to link to my article on beforefieldinit for the difference that a static constructor can make. I'm about to get off a train, but a search should find it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you create a class such as :

```
   class Foo
    {
        public static int y1 = 3;
        public static int x1 = y1;

        public static int X = Y; // 0
        public static int Y = 3; // 3


    }
```

and disassemble it you will see

```
        public static int y1 = 3;
00000021  mov         dword ptr ds:[009E9360h],3 
        public static int x1 = y1;
0000002b  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[009E9360h] 
00000030  mov         dword ptr ds:[009E9364h],eax 

        public static int X = Y; // 0
00000035  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[009E936Ch] 
0000003a  mov         dword ptr ds:[009E9368h],eax 
        public static int Y = 3; // 3
0000003f  mov         dword ptr ds:[009E936Ch],3
```

Y has not been initialized and its default value is 0.

Comment: Your second sentence is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

At first it seems a little weird, but in order to understand it, just remember they are fields, not local variables. Look at this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var a = field1;
    }

    int field1;        
}
```

you can use the field1 in MyMethod, as you know the order of declaration is not important (in this matter) for class members.
The case above is just like this.